# 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-406

Against my advice, my employer hired someone from fiver.com to create an online 'Task Manager'. They were given access to our database and FTP server. When I returned to work after 5 days, a certain page on our website was no longer working. The page contains a list of all our customers with several SQL filters. If I apply one of these filters through the search.php script, it will return the following error:

```
Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /admin.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Word Press is the main reason for this error. The 3rd party we hired from fiver.com installed a plug-in using Word Press. The application was, as expected, not up to a decent a standard and has since been removed from our site, but the error 406 still remains.

I have already tried creating a .htaccess page with the following content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

With this file uploaded onto the server, the error 406 is no longer displayed.
But the browser will automatically redirect to index.php.

I am running out of ideas!

Comment: Do you have mod_security installed?

Comment: Nope, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html Anything like that going on?